# How to fix "abnormal program termination" when using TREST components in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I get "abnormal program termination" error when i close my application.

When i use **TREST** components, i get the error above with a raised exception `First chance exception at $741FAA12. Exception class EBindingScopeFactoryError with message 'Scope class TBindSourceAdapterCustomScope not registered'.` on this specific line on **Data.Bind.ObjectScope** unit, i tried to investigate and debug many times, but the same error appears.

I use those **TREST** components in design time (not dynamically).

I couldn't figure out the solution to this.

Comment: which C++builder version? I do not know any TREST component its 3th party? if yes add at least a link to it for others to see. Any code to share? How can we spot if you got something wrong in code without seeing it? create MCVE that creates the exception.

Comment: I have C++ Builder in RAD Studio Berlin 10.1, the components you are looking for are chipped with this version of IDE **TRESTClient**, **TRESTRequest**, **TRESTResponse**, also the code you're looking for is working fine, the problem is when i **close the application**

Comment: I am not familiar with the component at all ... but your exception and the fact its on app exit hints you have either resource leak or missing some exiting code in OnDestroy event of your form ... it can be also related to destructor order if the component instances are destroyed sooner than their last usage ...

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem, i will take a look on that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug [RSP-19139](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19139), and is listed as fixed in RAD Studio 10.3.2.

Comment: That ticket is closed as "Cannot Reproduce" with a comment "Closing according to user's comment", but there is no comment saying it is actually "Fixed". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870301/65863) describes a real fix in more detail. Whether 10.3.2 actually fixes this, I do not know.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the bug in 10.2 and 10.3, but I haven't been able to test in 10.3.2. However, this page says it has been fixed: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.3.2 , so I'm fairly certain it has been fixed

Comment: I can confirm that it is fixed in 10.3.2.