# Abnormal program termination on shutdown with TRESTClient

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

When a program that has a `TRESTClient` components is shutdown, it will show an "Abnormal Program Termination" error.

Recently, we've upgraded a project from C++Builder 2009 to C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo. Afterwards, we added the new `TRESTClient` to our project. Now, every time we try to close the application, it shows this error. This means that an `abort()` call is probably made.

We've run the debugger until the end of the `tWinMain()` function, which shows that it happens after the return. This shows that the exception is thrown during application cleanup. In the included call stack, it shows `Data::Bind::Objectscope::Finalization`, and `UnregisterScope()` being called from there. This is most likely where the exception is thrown.

This problem seems very similar to the issue in [this forum post](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228731). Remy Lebeau describes this as a bug where, if an item is not found while unregistering, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is fixed as of 10.3.2:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195297/6852057

**To fix it in an older version:**

The issue has to do with the link order of two libraries, namely "bindengine.lib" and "bindcomp.lib".

When "bindcomp.lib" is linked in BEFORE "bindengine.lib" you will see this problem, and for some frustrating reason the IDE insists in placing the them in wrong order. So to resolve the issue.

1. close your project that shows the problem in the IDE.
2. load the project's .cbproj into a text editor (HINT: NOT the IDE)
3. search for the "" tag.
4. switch the position of the two libs "...;bindengine.lib;bindcomp.lib;... " so as to have the "bindengine" BEFORE "bindcomp".
5. repeat the process for any other "" (as you might have more than one configuration)
6. repeat 3. to 5. for the tag ""
7. save the project file.
8. open it in the IDE and Build OR Clean and Make the project again. So that the EXE gets re-linked.

Comment: Are we sure this is actually fixed in 10.3.2? The answer you link to above as proof merely claims it is fixed because it links to a bug report that has been closed in 10.3.2, but if you actually read the ticket it was closed as "Cannot Reproduce" with a comment "Closing according to user's comment", but there is no comment that says it is actually "Fixed".

Comment: Good question. 
I have been able to reproduce the bug in 10.2 and 10.3, but I haven't been able to test in 10.3.2. However, this page says it has been fixed: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.3.2 , so I'm fairly certain it has been fixed